# Replace method changes size of QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I want to manipulate a 32 bit write command which I have stored in a QByteArray. But the thing that confuses me is that my QByteArray changes size and I cannot figure out why that happens.

My code:

```
const char CMREFCTL[] = {0x85,0x00,0x00,0x0B};
QByteArray test = QByteArray::fromRawData(CMREFCTL, sizeof(CMREFCTL));

qDebug()<<test.toHex();

const char last1 = 0x0B;
const char last2 = 0x0A;

test.replace(3,1,&last2);
qDebug()<<test.toHex();
test.replace(3,1,&last1);
qDebug()<<test.toHex();
```

Generates:

```
"0x8500000b"
"0x8500000a0ba86789"
"0x8500000ba867890ba86789"
```

I expected the following output:

```
"0x8500000b"
"0x8500000a"
"0x8500000b"
```

Using *test.replace(3,1,&last2,1)* works but I dont see why my code above dont give the same result.

Best regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the documentation for the relevant method:

> QByteArray & QByteArray::replace ( int pos, int len, const char *
>   after )
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Replaces len bytes from index position pos with the zero terminated
>   string after.
>
> Notice: this can change the length of the byte array.

You are not giving the byte array a zero-terminated string, but a pointer to a single char.  So it will scan forward in memory from that pointer until it hits a 0, and treat all that memory as the string to replace with.

If you just want to change a single character `test[3] = last2;` should do what you want.

Comment: I'll note that this causes undefined behavior, so it may have just as easily crashed

Comment: Is there no way around this?  I'm storing floats in a `QByteArray` for a point cloud, and whenever I operate on this container, i.e. a function that adds a value to every X coordinate, the container grows.  I call `QByteArray::resize()` at the end, but this seems inefficient.  Maybe I should just build a `QByteArray` from scratch instead of calling `replace()` on a copy of my original `QByteArray`?